# 一部ユーザのアバターがプロフィールバナーで消える。The avatar of some users disappears in flair

Tags: バグ

通常、全てのテーマにアバターが含まれる。
Avatars are usually included in all themes.
https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community/flair
[image: 通常の例]

一部のユーザの、一部のテーマで、アバターが消える。
Some users, with some themes, the avatar disappears.
<del>日本語版のみで発見している。

I have found only in the Japanese version StackOverflow.</del>

[image: アバターが消えているユーザの例]

---

追記:

質問投稿時は例えば以下のユーザでこの現象が見られましたが、現在は直っています。
https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/3054/mjy/flair
https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/4236/sayuri/flair
https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/9498/gen/flair
https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/7232/stackdestroyer/flair
https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/6119/joy1192/flair
画像は、

> 24 ～ 36 時間ごとに更新されます

との事なので、更新がうまくいったのでしょうか。
本日は例えば、以下のユーザのバナーがおかしくなっていました。
https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/7651/%E3%81%B2%E3%82%8D%E3%81%AE%E3%81%B6/flair
https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/8848/knaito/flair
https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/17127/ryo/flair

サーバ側のネットワークの問題でアバターの取得がタイムアウトする事がある、などの再現が難しい現象かもしれませんね。
クライアント側（私のブラウザ環境）の問題では無いと思います。バナーは一枚の画像としてサーバ側で生成されている筈ですので。

---

追記2:

使用するネットワークによって見える画像が違う事が分かりました。
今現在、問題が確認出来たバナーを一つ（これも時間が来て更新されれば、直るかもしれないですね）以下に載せておきます。

URL: https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/flair/7651.png
アメリカからアクセス:
[image: バナー USA経由]
ロシアからアクセス:
[image: バナー ロシア経由]
日本からアクセス:
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

---

Flair fails to show the avatars for some users. It seems that the flair are updated every 24-36 hours, so the flair that isn't working changes from day to day, but this is what it looks like normally:

[image: 通常の例]

This is what it looks like when the avatar doesn't load properly:

[image: アバターが消えているユーザの例]

This is not limited to a specific site or theme, and for a single user some themes may display the avatar while it isn't shown for others.

Whether or not an avatar appears also seems to depend on where you are accessing from. Here are examples all taken from the same time but using different proxies for access:

From a US Proxy (Avatar appears):

[image: バナー USA経由]

From a Russian Proxy (no Avatar):

[image: バナー ロシア経由]

From Japan (no Avatar):

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: キャシングかな？再現できないので、開発者が治せないと思います。

Comment: @jmac さんには例えば以下の3つは正常に見えていますか？  http://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/flair/7651.png http://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/flair/8848.png?theme=clean http://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/flair/17127.png?theme=clean 今時点では私から見るとアバターが消えています。 キャッシュクリアしても、スマートフォンなどの環境でも、変わらないです。

Comment: USAのネットワーク経由だと正常に見えていることを確認しました。日本やロシア経由のアクセスをいくつか試すと駄目です。ですので、開発者の方にはプロキシなどを使ってもらはないと、再現は出来ないかもしれないですね。

Comment: なるほど、CDNの問題かもしれませんね。開発者に連絡します。

Comment: （上記のリンク、三つとも見えます）

Comment: @jmac mjyさんが指摘されたURLでは再現しませんでしたが、ID順に200件ほど取得してみると確かに5%程度のユーザーでアバターが消えていました。

Comment: 日本語版のみ、としていましたが本家StackOverflowでも見られたので訂正します。現時点での例、 http://stackoverflow.com/users/flair/1620779.png?theme=dark http://stackoverflow.com/users/flair/4952130.png

Comment: adblockとかghosteryを利用していますか？

Comment: @jmac  使用してません。PCのブラウザに限らず、コマンドラインのシンプルなクライアント(`wget`)や、スマートフォンでも再現します。

Comment: 開発者は確認中です。こちら側だと思っていますが、原因はまだ特定できていません。